# How to recognize DateTime fields as such when assigning a Json.net JArray to a Grid?

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net

My winform client requests a DataTable from server to assign to Grid on forms.
The server will return DataTable as JSON using JSON.net.
We use `JArray.Parse` to read the returned string and assign this JArray to Grid.
The data is displayed well except for DateTime fields.
All of fields with DateTime type have names that contain "DATE" or "TIME".
I wonder if there is any way to parse JTokens that belong to these fields to `DateTime` format?

I am using C# with VS2013 .Net 4.0

My returned json string is:

```
[
    { "ORDER_ID":10, "CREATED_DATE":"20160617181008", "NOTE":"Hello" },
    { "ORDER_ID":20, "CREATED_DATE":"20160616140302", "NOTE":"Ciao" }
]
```

I parse this JSON string as follows:

```
JArray table = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
```

And I assign the variable "table" to DataSource of Grid Control.
I am using the following C# date format: "yyyyMMddHHmmss".

The grid will display CREATED_DATE column as: 20160617181008 and 20160616140302.

Comment: 1) What language are you using?  c#?  vb.net?  2) Please [edit] your question to show an example of the JSON you are receiving - as embedded text, not as an image, so we could paste it into visual studio for testing.  3) Also, please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, that is not working.  See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easiest if you could output dates and times from the server to JSON in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  If a date string is formatted in this style, LINQ to JSON will automatically recognize it as a `DateTime` and deserialize it as such.  See [Deserializing from JSON with LINQ](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializewithlinq.htm) and [Serializing Dates in JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) for details.

That being said, you can post-process your `JArray` to convert the [value](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty_Value.htm) of any [property](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) with `"DATE"` or `"TIME"` in its name to a `DateTime` as follows:

```
var table = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

var format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // Change if necessary
var style = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal; // Change if necessary.

foreach (var property in table.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(p => (p.Name.Contains("DATE") || p.Name.Contains("TIME")) && p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String))
{
    var value = (string)property.Value;
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, culture, style, out date))
        property.Value = date;
}
```